# Does Ubuntu still (actively) support the 32-bit PowerPC architecture?

Tags: lts, powerpc, architecture

As Debian has dropped support for PowerPC 32-bit in Debian 9, does Ubuntu still actively support (i.e. still make releases for) 32-bit PowerPC?

16.04 seems to be the last release, but I can't find anything on if future LTS releases will be supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but the answer is no.

16.04 LTS is the last Ubuntu version for Power PC. Lubuntu 16.04 LTS will be supported for 3 years (until April 2019) and the program packages, that belong to standard Ubuntu or Ubuntu Server will be supported for 5 years (until April 2021).